# Does the letter "X" at the end of a line make that syllable long?

Tags: poetry, scansion

In scansion, a vowel is long by position if there are two or more consonants between it and the next vowel.  Can a vowel be long by position if it ends a line and there is no next vowel?  E.g. is the "E" in "REX" long if it is the last syllable in a line?  I am particularly concerned with the case for dactylic hexameter if it makes a difference for the answer to the question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Very interesting question. First, I think you mean "if there are two or more consonants". Secondly, I think the question that must be answered first is this: can a syllable in ancipital position (denoted by a cross: "can be either long or short") be long or short at all? Or does it have no decided length?

Comment: In general, though, what makes a syllable long is either a long vowel, or closure by means of a consonant. When you see *rex et*, the syllables are *rek-set*, and that's why the first syllable is long. In *cor et*, the syllables are *co-ret*; and the o itself is short, so the first syllable is short, because it is open and it doesn't contain a long vowel. Because *rex* can never use all of its ending consonants, it must always contain a long syllable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*In scansion, a vowel is long by position if there are more than two consonants between it and the next vowel.*

This is the usual way of putting it, but it's inacccurate/misleading in a couple of ways.

First, it's not really the *vowel* that is long by position; it's the *syllable* that is long, or in a different terminology, "heavy". (Linguists these days speak of "light" and "heavy" syllables, to avoid possible confusion with "long" and "short" vowels.)

Second and relatedly, the reason that a vowel followed by two or more consonants is "long by position" is really that in such a case, the syllable ends with a consonant, and is therefore heavy: e.g. a word like *centum* gets syllabified *cen-tum*, and any syllable that ends with a consonant (like *cen*) is heavy, i.e. can fill a "long" verse position.

What this all leads to is that it doesn't matter whether the word is at the end of a line or not: a word like *rex* will always form a heavy syllable, so will always count as metrically long.

(That said, since you're asking about dactylic hexameter: in that meter, *any* syllable, light or heavy, can stand at the end of a line, so in that context, everything I said above actually doesn't matter. Even a syllable with a short vowel and no final consonant can stand at the end of a hexameter line.)

Comment: ...And additionally, "rex" had an actually long vowel, so the syllable would be heavy even without the final consonants.

Comment: Do you mean that a syllable ending in a (single) consonant is always heavy? I wouldn't scan so at the end of a word if the next one starts with a vowel. Consider the (mock-up) pentameter: *Illud abest mihi nunc excruciorque ab eo.* Or would you say that the second and third syllables are *lu* and *da* instead of *lud* and *a* (and similarly in *ab eo*)? *Rex* has a double consonant so it's different.

Comment: The last syllable of a verse is ALWAYS metrically long. This is true not only for hexameter, but for all metres.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta In such cases, syllabification in verse crosses word boundaries. So yes: *il-lu-da-best*.

Comment: @fdb That was actually the way I initially phrased it. But since the long/short contrast is neutralized in that position, I wonder if there's any good basis for calling such syllables "long" (rather than simply saying that the meter allows any syllable to stand in that position).

Comment: @TKR. Risking the danger of excessive pedanticism I would suggest that if the hexameter verse is analysed as six dactylic “feet”, then the last foot of the line must be analysed as long+long, not as long+short, as the latter would not be a complete foot. You will find that the same is true of the other metres.